# <a> bug with mailto in HTML

Tags: html, css, tags

I was trying to add a <a href="mailto:xyz@xyz.pl> but something strange occurred on my website. I was trying to remove it but it didn't work. Any help will be appreciated. I am just a beginner.

```
<a href="mailto:xyz@xyz.pl">
<button>
<div class="rectangle"></div>
</button>
</a>

<a href="mailto:xyz@xyz.pl">
<button>
<div class="contact" a href="mail">
    <p>contact us</p>
</div>
</button>
</a>
```

[image]

Comment: Why is there a button inside of a link? and a paragraph inside of a button. Your HTML is very invalid.

Comment: Your question is very unclear. Are you trying to add it or remove it? [What does "didn't work" mean?](http://idownvotedbecau.se/itsnotworking/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this :

```
<a  href="mailto:xyz@xyz.pl">Contact Us</a>
```

You don't need `<button></button>` inside `<a href=""></a>`

Answer (score -2):

You don't need an  tag inside an  tag. Just use this:

`<a href="mailto:xyz@xyz.pl">Contact us</a>`

and then style the  tag to a button shape.
Let me know if it worked.

Answer (score -2):

First of all question is unclear.

But you can just use

`<a href="mailto:xyz@xyz.pl">Contact us</a>`

to get an item named Contact Us which is having a redirecting link.
You don't need to just create a button inside a href tag.

Else just clearly explain your idea regarding href tag